# About WebView In NestedScrollView. Can not show bottom content

Tags: android, webview, nestedscrollview

I can not display webview bottom content casue by using NestedScrollView.
The bottom bar not apps bar.

I am sorry to my English. Thanks~

dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

[image]
[image]

My Code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/view_toobar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should more read about Material widgets, because you use some new parameters in your NewstedScrollView. That parameters is scrolled space below, from ActionBar size. Just remove it, or update your code!

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: I had try this code , and could not disappear too.


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

Comment: I think it is the NestedScrollView increase height automatically , so my website float menu could not show on screen. But actually , it show on website footer.